# How can I parse people's full names into user names in Perl?

Tags: string, perl, parsing, substring

I need to convert a name in the format Parisi, Kenneth into the format kparisi.

Does anyone know how to do this in Perl?

Here is some sample data that is abnormal:

Zelleb, Charles F.,,IV
Eilt, John,, IV
Wods, Charles R.,,III
Welkt, Craig P.,,Jr.

These specific names should end up as czelleb, jeilt, cwoods, cwelkt, etc.

---

I have one more condition that is ruining my name builder
O'Neil, Paul
so far, Vinko Vrsalovic's answer is working the best when weird/corrupt names are in the mix, but this example above would come out as "pneil"... id be damned below judas if i cant get that o between the p and the n

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
vinko@parrot:~$ cat genlogname.pl
```

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @list;
push @list, "Zelleb, Charles F.,,IV";
push @list, "Eilt, John,, IV";
push @list, "Woods, Charles R.,,III";
push @list, "Welkt, Craig P.,,Jr.";

for my $name (@list) {
        print gen_logname($name)."\n";
}

sub gen_logname {
        my $n = shift;
        #Filter out unneeded characters
        $n =~ s/['-]//g;
        #This regex will grab the lastname a comma, optionally a space (the 
        #optional space is my addition) and the first char of the name, 
        #which seems to satisfy your condition
        $n =~ m/(\w+), ?(.)/;
        return lc($2.$1);
}
```

```
vinko@parrot:~$ perl genlogname.pl
czelleb
jeilt
cwoods
cwelkt
```

Comment: how come I didn't get notified of all the answers? I took a long time and I wondered why nobody had answered yet... heh!

Comment: dont know... they came pretty quick.. i only posted this q about 10 minutes ago.... thanks for the input anyway, i think rasmussen's answer is working fine so far

Comment: hey vinko... im seeing that last names like "O'neil, Pat" and "Parisi-Caid, Kenneth" come in as pneil and kcaid.... the second one is fine, but the O'neil, Pat would be better to come in as poneil

Comment: Here it is modified. If you need to filter out more characters than ' and - you can add them between the [] below the "filter out unneeded charaters" comment

Comment: The only thing that bothers me about this is that I posted a question very similar to this on Perl Monks, and would have gotten more help from SO than from Perl Monks for the same question  (This was quite a few months ago).

Answer (score 6):

I would start by filtering the abnormal data so you only have regular names. Then something like this should do the trick

```
$t = "Parisi, Kenneth";
$t =~ s/(.+),\s*(.).*/\l$2\l$1/;
```

Comment: i ran into a roadblock "Marphy-Smulka, Mara" comes in as "mmarphy-smulka"

how do you think i can get rid of the "-" or just use the first part of the last name excluding any non-alphabetical characters

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$name =~ s/(\w+),\s(\w)/$2$1/;
$name = lc $name;
```

`\w` here matches an alphanumerical character. If you want to be more specific, you could also use `[a-z]` instead, and pass the `i` flag (case insensitive):

```
$name =~ s/([a-z]+)\s([a-z])/$2$1/i;
```

Comment: Konrad, you had it backwards - it's supposed to be the whole last name (which comes first) and then the first initial (which comes second)

Comment: Ouch. Thanks for correcting it, Paul. I actually tested the code before posting but somehow I was satisfied with my wrong result. ;-)

Comment: Sorry to say it, but you're no Jon Skeet. :-)

Comment: yeah i just tested it also... it looked close, but i didnt get the goods

Comment: @“you're no Jon Skeet” – fancy that. But perhaps he’s me and created a second account to anonymously post second-rate solutions to fight his boredom. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one line solution, assuming you store all the names in a file called "names" (one per line) and you will do duplicated name detection somehow later.

```
cat names | perl -e 'while(<>) {/^\s*(\S*)?,\s*(\S)/; print lc "$2$1\n";}' | sed s/\'//g
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your input data is comma-separated. To me, the clearest way to do this would be split into components, and then generate the login names from that:

```
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my ($last, $first) = split /,/, lc $_;
    $last =~ s/[^a-z]//g;  # strip out nonletters
    $first =~ s/[^a-z]//g; # strip out nonletters
    my $logname = substr($first, 0, 1) . $last;
    print $logname, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $rowfetch =~ s/['-]//g; #All chars inside the [ ] will be filtered out.
    $rowfetch =~ m/(\w+), ?(.)/;
    $rowfetch = lc($2.$1);
```

this is how I ended up using Vinko Vrsalovic's solution... its inside a while loop that goes through a sql query result ... thanks again vinko

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    say abbreviate($_);
}


sub abbreviate {
    for ( @_ ) {
        s/[-']+//g;
        tr/A-Z/a-z/;
        tr/a-z/ /c;
        return "$2$1" if /([a-z]+)\s+([a-z])/;
    }
}


__DATA__
Zelleb, Charles F.,,IV
Eilt, John,, IV
Woods, Charles R.,,III
Welkt, Craig P.,,Jr.
O'Neil, Paul
```

#### output

```
czelleb
jeilt
cwoods
cwelkt
poneil
```